# How do I replace the contents of one variable with that of another?

Tags: stata

In essence I want to tell Stata that when variable `F11 = "Ya" replace` it with the value in variable `Score` (SCREENSHOTS attached). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvfDl.png)

So I want to replace the contents of the variable `F11` as well as all the other indicator numbers (`A01`, `B02`, `C03` etc.) with the score that applies to that indicator.

So for example, for the first observation in the screenshot, that person received a score of 19.88 (variable is `Score`) for the indicator `F11` (variable is Kat_Indikator_KG) and the label `"Ya"` under the variable `F11` tells us that that individual was scored for this category.

What I would like to do is replace the `"Ya"` with the score obtained in variable `Score` and I would like to do that for all the indicator variables e.g. `A01`, `B02`, `C03`.

So far I've tried the following, but none seem to work:

```
replace F11 = Score if Kat_Indikator_KG == "F-11"
replace F11 = Score if Kat_Indikator_KG == "F-11"
replace F11 = Score if Kat_Indikator_KG == "F-11" & F11 == "Ya"
replace F11 = Score if F11 == "Ya"
```

Screenshots are attached and help is appreciated!

Comment: Cross-posted on Statalist: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1557775-how-do-i-replace-the-contents-of-one-variable-with-that-of-another. It's a good idea to tell people so they don't have to spend time to answer your question a second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot replace a string variable with a numeric value. You could replace "Ya" with "1" and `destring` it, so something like this:

```
ds Kat Score, not
foreach var of varlist `r(varlist)' {
    replace `var' = "1" if `var' == "Ya"
    destring `var', replace
    replace `var' == Score if `var' == 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks Wouter! Dank je wel!
​​​​​​​With a few edits your method worked! Saved me a lot of time too!